# What happened to with the alternate installer in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: alternate

http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/

vs.: 

http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/

In the "old" times Ubuntu had a separated "ncurses-based" installer when people wanted to use Full Disc Encryption when installing. It was named: Alternate installer.

**Question:** What happened to the alternate install CD? Are there any

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The alternate installer has been ended. Full disc encryption is now possible via the "normal" one.

Comment: And what about RAID configuration?

Comment: That's what I was looking for too. Le sigh.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [alternate installer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Alternate_ISO), provided by the Lubuntu devs. Other options for download are available at the Ubuntu [CD image repository](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/). Since alternate images are [still being built](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily/current/) for Lubuntu (as of  11-Sep-2014), I'd imagine you'd have this option at least for 14.10.