# Can't find LTSP option when booting from Ubuntu Server ISO images

Tags: server, virtualbox, vmware, ltsp

I have tried using a Windows & Ubuntu host machine running both VMware pro & Virtual box to install an LTSP server from an Ubuntu server installation iso.

When I start up the Ubuntu server iso in the player, press <kbd>F4</kbd> the LTSP installation option isn't there.

Any ideas what's going on? I have tried using Ubuntu 64 bit server 12.04, 14.04 & 15.04 iso images & I can't find the LTSP install on any of them.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Alternate CD and not server iso.

Quoted from: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuLTSP/LTSPQuickInstall

> Starting with the Hardy Heron (8.04) release the LTSP installer
>   functionality was moved to the Ubuntu alternate CD.

But alternate CD is [not available for Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457513/what-happened-to-with-the-alternate-installer-in-ubuntu-14-04) but you can still use the one for 12.04. Download it from here:

- [64 bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.5-alternate-amd64.iso)
- [32 bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.5-alternate-i386.iso)

If you want you can  install it after installing any version of Ubuntu:

```
sudo -i
add-apt-repository --yes ppa:ts.sch.gr
apt-get update
apt-get --yes --install-recommends install dnsmasq ltsp-server-standalone ltsp-client ldm-ubuntu-theme ltsp-config dnsmasq
echo 'IPAPPEND=3' >> /etc/ltsp/update-kernels.conf
/usr/share/ltsp/update-kernels
```

more info from here: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuLTSP/ltsp-pnp